# Is it possible to run specific Gauge specs from within a C# application

Tags: c#, getgauge, protractor-net

I want to wait for a message (from RabbitMQ) wherein I will receive the data required to run a Gauge spec file. Now I will be creating a C# application that uses NServiceBus to handle the incoming message and from there I want to trigger the Gauge spec with some parameters.

So what I am looking for is a way to trigger a Gauge spec from within a running C# application.

I am able to run Gauge spec file as Command Prompt commands using `gauge run specs` command. But want to see if there is another way to trigger this.

Answer (score 0):

Gauge gives you the power to specs as you wish, through tags or specific scenarios. e.g : `gauge run --tags "tag1, tag2" specs`. see  https://docs.gauge.org/execution.html for information.